# Harnack Inequality

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, linear-pde

In the Han and Lin book there is a Harnak inequality for elliptic operators of the kind:
$$
L u = D_i \big(a^{ij}\, D_ju\big),
$$
and the constant $C$ in the Harnack inequality does not depend on the radius of the ball on which I take the $\sup$ and the $\inf$. 
(Theorem 4.17, *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations*, Han & Lin)

In the book of Gilbarg and Trudinger, there is another version of the Harnkack inequality for elliptic operators of the kind:
$$
L u = D_i\big(a^{ij} \,D_j u + b^j \,u \big) + c^i\,D_iu + d\, u
$$
but in this case the constant does depend on the size of the ball (Theorem 8.20, *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order*, Gilbarg & Trudinger).

I need something in between. Namely I need an Harnack inequality for operator of the kind
$$
L u = D_i\big(a^{ij} \,D_j u \Big) + c^i \, D_iu
$$
but such that the constant does not depend on the radius of the ball. Does exist such result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I agree with you. Here is the link http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039608001770

Comment: It would help if you included the desired inequality in your answer, links may become invalid over time.